# scope.$watch ( when DOM modified by json return, how I did notice directive to add value to it.) angular

Tags: angularjs

My directive :

```
App.directive('dropdownSelected', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch(
                function () { return element[0].childNodes.length; },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                        alert(newValue);
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
})
```

My dropdown HTML file:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-controller="userWorkspaces">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="dp fa fa-gear"></i> <dropdown-Selected></dropdown-Selected><span class="caret">       </span>
</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setSelectedWorkspace(workspace)" class="vtDropdown">{{ workspace.WorkspaceName }}</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Data comes from a controller in JSON format.

I fount out, directive always loaded earlier than controller, and  `element[0].childNodes.length` and `newvalue` are always 0. Can anyone tell me why never call back and newValue?

Comment: Can you post the controller code? It's very hard to understand what happens otherwise.

Comment: Also, why are you using `element[0]` and not just `element`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, here is the solution I can think of:

1.Add following scope to your directive (here I have added `dataFromController: '='`) -

```
App.directive('dropdownSelected', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            dataFromController: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            // set scope.dataUpdated = false
            // update your element inside here using dataFromController which has value to update your directive 
            // once your update element here set scope.dataUpdated = true
            // then add watch for 'dataUpdated' and do the stuff you wanted to do on change of that
            scope.$watch(
                         'dataUpdated' },
                         function (newValue, oldValue) {
                             if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                                 alert(newValue);
                             }
                         }
                       )
        }
    }
})
```

2.Inside HTML add attribute to your directive like this

```html
<div class="btn-group" ng-controller="userWorkspaces">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="dp fa fa-gear"></i> <dropdown-Selected data-from-controller="jsonObjFromController"></dropdown-Selected><span class="caret">       </span>
</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setSelectedWorkspace(workspace)" class="vtDropdown">{{ workspace.WorkspaceName }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

3.Inside your controller update `$scope.jsonObjFromController` with JSON data